# Get only products with images using Amazon Product API

Tags: amazon-product-api

Is it possible with the Amazon Product API to return items from Amazon that have images using ItemSearch and ignore products that do not have images?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Amazon Product API does not allow us to filter the search results. It only allows searching a given index by keywords.

To only get results with images, you will have to write code that discards results with no images.